# Bootstrap 4 row extends outside of container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I decided to try using bootstrap and opted for version 4.

So I have a pretty good template structured out and noticed that the row for the main content extends out past the bounds of the container div. It is the only row on the page that does that.

I tried changing spacing with margin or padding on either/both elements and it didn't seem to change anything.
I also tried containing the main content inside of a section tag, since the other two rows are contained within header/footer tags and they remain within the bounds. This also did not work.

[image: screenshot]

I highlighted the container just to show its bounding box. I also have the padding removed from it in this screenshot, it is the same problem either way though.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Air Technology West</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- fontawesome CDN embed -->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f13a1bd68c.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Header area -->
      <header class="pt-3 px-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/logo1.png"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul class="contact-info">
              <li class="ph-local"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> xxx-xxx-xxxx</li>
              <li class="ph-fax"><span class="fnt-sm">Fax: </span><i class="fa fa-fax fa-fw"></i> xxx-xxx-xxxx</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div><!--END ROW-->
    </header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md nav-main d-flex flex-row">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-main-toggle" aria-controls="nav-main-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span><span class="btn-collapse"> MENU</span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-main-toggle">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <p class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">Home</a></p>
          <p class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">About Us</a></p>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Compressors</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Spray Equipment</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Parts & Accessories</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">All Major Products</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <p class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">Services</a></p>
          <p class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!--===========END header area==============-->

    <!--===========CAROUSEL area================-->
    <div id="carousel-main" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <a href="#"><img class="d-block w-100" src="img/headline_compressors.PNG" alt="First slide"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <a href="#"><img class="d-block w-100" src="img/headline_spray.PNG" alt="Second slide"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <a href="#"><img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/720x300" alt="Third slide"></a>
        </div>
      </div><!--END CAROUSEL INNER-->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-main" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-main" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--===========END carousel area============-->

    <!--===========PAGE content==============-->
    <section id="page-content">
      <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card mt-3">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Service</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="card mt-3">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Products</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="card mt-3">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Parts & accessories</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </aside>

        <article class="main col-md-9 col-sm-12 px-3 mt-3">
          <p>This is the main content area</p>
        </article>
      </div><!--END ROW-->
    </section><!--END PAGE CONTENT-->
    <!--============END page content===============-->

    <!--=============footer area===============-->
    <footer class=" my-3 px-3">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h3 class="border-bottom">Quick links</h3>
          <nav class="nav row nav-footer">
            <a class="nav-link col-md-4 col-sm-6" href="#">Products</a>
            <a class="nav-link col-md-4 col-sm-6" href="#">Services</a>
            <a class="nav-link col-md-4 col-sm-6" href="#">About Us</a>
            <a class="nav-link col-md-4 col-sm-6" href="#">Contact Info</a>
            <a class="nav-link col-md-4 col-sm-6" href="#">Directons</a>
            <a class="nav-link col-md-4 col-sm-6" href="#">Site Map</a>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 contact-info">
          <h3 class="border-bottom">Contact Info</h3>
          <p class="ph-local"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> xxx-xxx-xxxx</p>
          <p class="ph-fax"><span class="fnt-sm">Fax: </span><i class="fa fa-fax fa-fw"></i> xxx-xxx-xxxx</p>
          <p class="address"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></i> ADDRESS</p>
        </div>

      </div><!--END ROW-->
    </footer>
    <!--==============END footer area================-->

  </div><!--===============END CONTAINER===============-->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: add styles.css file.

```
html{
  font-family: verdana, helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}

nav a{
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav .nav-link, .nav .dropdown-item {
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-toggle{
  color: black;
}

.nav a:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.nav a:active{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.navbar{
  padding: .1rem;
}

.navbar-toggler{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
/*********************3. LAYOUT********************/
#carousel-main{
  position:relative;
}

.carousel-button-right{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 25%;
}

.carousel-button-left{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  left: 25%;
}

.carousel-button-center{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 50%;
}
/*********************4. MODULES*******************/

/********4.1 HEADER *********/
.logo{
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.contact-info{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.fnt-sm{
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.ph-local{
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

/********4.2 MAIN NAV********/

.btn-collapse{
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/********FOOTER********/

.border-bottom{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

/*********************5. STATES********************/

/*********************6. THEME*********************/

body{
  background-image: url("../img/escheresque_ste.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

header, footer, .navbar, .main{
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  header *{
    text-align:center;
  }

  nav .nav-item{
    text-align: center;
  }


  aside{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  footer *{
    text-align: center;
  }

  footer nav .nav-item{
    text-align: center;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  footer.contact-info *{
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works as expected for me.

Comment: Work as expected also for me. Your error is somewhere else. Try to post your style.css file.

Comment: Posted css file. Thank you

Comment: `.row`(s) should be immediate children of `.container`, `.container-fluid`, or any other class with default horizontal padding  (`15px`), e.g: `.col`, `.navbar`, `.card-body`, etc... In your case, you have to apply `.container-fluid` to `#page-content`. Look at any of bootstrap 4's examples. You'll never find a `.row` placed in a parent without the horizontal padding (unless it has `.no-gutters`, but that removes gutters, which you probably don't want).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The .row in bootstrap is giving a margin right and left of -15px, override it with a in-line style="margin: auto" and you should be fine.

The aside has a default padding left and right of 15, so in your case you should set the padding-left to 0 making the content fit the grid properly.

```
<section id="page-content">
  <div class="row" style="margin: auto">
    <aside class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 0">
      <div class="card mt-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Service</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="card mt-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Products</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="card mt-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Parts & accessories</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </aside>

    <article class="main col-md-9 col-sm-12 px-3 mt-3">
      <p>This is the main content area</p>
    </article>
  </div><!--END ROW-->
</section><!--END PAGE CONTENT-->
```

Comment: Well, that almost fixes it. Things are still messed up on smaller screen sizes though. Also, the other row divs have the same -15px margin, so that doesn't explain why just the one is extending outside the box. Thank you

Comment: If you mean the left side on smaller screens, a margin: auto instead of margin-right: 0 would be more appropriate. I'll look into the exact problem, because that brings your images over a bit.

Comment: Found a fix for whole problem, will update my answer now, but it involves removing the padding-left from the aside, and setting margin:auto on the row.

Comment: This messes up mobile view. The proper solution is to wrap in `.container-fluid`. I've added an answer with a more thorough explanation. Also note that `.row.no-gutter` has the disadvantage of removing the gutters (the columns padding) which is not always desirable. Having to add them back is more tedious than adding some padding around the row, at the appropriate intervals, using a class which was designed as a `.row` wrapper.

Comment: Add `container-fluid` class to `#page-content`. That's the correct solution, because it doesn't fight/counter Bootstrap's CSS, it uses it as it was designed.

Answer (score 30):

Adding the 'no-gutters' class `class='row no-gutters'` to your bootstrap 4 rows is also a nice way to get rid of margins and paddings.

> The gutters between columns in our predefined grid classes can be
>   removed with .no-gutters. This removes the negative margins from .row
>   and the horizontal padding from all immediate children columns.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Comment: This should be the right answer. I extend a bit, you should use:  class="row no-gutters"

Comment: I did this and my row got skinnier with big blank white columns on both sides of the browser window.

Comment: this works. I'm glad it has become part of the bootstrap spec.

Comment: This has the disadvantage of removing the gutters (column paddings). The proper solution is to wrap `.row` in `.container-fluid`, which was designed as `.row` wrapper. Also note `.row` changes its margins responsively and `.container-fluid` accounts for that. If not obvious, the wrapper is only necessary when the immediate `.row` parent does not already have a minimum horizontal padding of `15px` (e.g: `.col`, `.container`, `.navbar`, `.card-body`, etc).

Answer (score 9):

use the class `mr-0` instead of `style="margin-right: 0"` that's the bootstrap 4 way.

Comment: Yeah it is. Can't say I like this feature, but oh well. I did end up using this method with the knowledge that Brock brought up.

Comment: and ml=0 for margin left. thanks worked

Comment: Wrapping in `.container-fluid` is the proper solution (and the *"bootstrap way"*).  All one needs to do is inspect the source code of any bootstrap official theme layout and you'll see it used anywhere the `.row`'s parent doesn't already have a horizontal padding of `15px` or bigger.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `mx-0` to the overflowing element will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**tl,dr:** - wrap `.row`(s) in `.container-fluid`

---

To counter the negative margins of `.row`, without losing the gutters (column default horizontal padding) and without messing up the mobile, place the `.row`(s) in a wrapper with at least `15px` right and left padding, such as `.container`, `.container-fluid`, `.navbar`, `.card-body`, etc...

**Important**: `.row` changes its negative margins responsively, but both `.container` and `.container-fluid` account for that, as they were designed to work together.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap adds an automatic horizontal spacing to row classes. So override it by setting the horizontal space (i.e. margin) to 0, just like;

```
<div class="row mx-0">
  ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering above answers, sometimes you need to edit default CSS property in your project.
so if your want to Apply `no-gutters` or any CSS property, you can simply change that property on main **CSS** / **SASS** file like this:

```
.row {
    margin: 0;
}
```

this hack will remove no-gutters margin from all **row** in your project!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to add .row{width:100%} to your css
this way you don't have to change padding of col inside your row
it is working for me no more overflow